# Move a GameObject by its child objects

Tags: unity-game-engine

I wanted to create some evolution like "game". I make some bones, muscles, etc. When I hit play the *creature* moved but when I've checked the distance it stayed 0. What I've discovered was that all individual child elements moved but the containing GameObject was stil at the same position.

What is the (correct) way to make changes of a child object affect the parent object? Like moving legs to move the person.

The question seemed clear in my head but after reading your questions, remarks and comments I needed elaborate more:

I understand the basic idea of walking animations and such (i think). But here I'm trying to move a creature by itself. At first purely random movement and hopefully later on via a neural network.

In the sample screenshot below you see a *creature*, the spheres are colored for its weight and the beams between the spheres are the bone/muscle. And my *creature* limbs do move by pulsating the bone/muscles... but the position of the parent object stay the same. The magenta line is the position of the parent. I would like that the position of the parent would follow the center of its elements.

[image: Sample of a "creature"]

Comment: How exactly you want the parent object to behave? Should it follow its children to a given distance, or just be exactly where one of the children are? Please be more specific on what you want to achieve

Comment: Generally the motion is applied to the root object and not the individual parts.  Legs on a person object dont actually move, they play an animation and the root object moves.  Trying to move the parent after the child has moved is going to cause problems and just wont feel right.  You would have to get the offset from the parent, unparent top level children from the parent object, move the parent object, then parent everything back... not very pretty.  Or you could move each top level child using said offset after moving the parent.  It can be done, but most likely shouldn't.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is a bit unclear to what exactly it is you are after. However, if you want the child-parent behaviour become reveresed in a way that child becomes parent and parent becomes child just for function `A()` , you can simply swap the child and parents relation in `A()` itself,

As an example,

```
void A()
{
   child.transform.SetParent(parent.transform.parent);
   parent.transform.SetParent(child.transform);
   
   ... // your A function
   
   parent.transform.SetParent(child.transform.parent);
   child.transform.SetParent(parent.transfotm);
}
```